# How to print or echo some text in new page if the if statement is true in php

Tags: php, html

Hello Every One i am new to coding and now i am learning php and html below i submited the code and  i want to print Hello World in a new page if the given user name and password is correct but it is printing in the same page can any one help me Thanks in Advance

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter The Username"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            <input type="reset"  value="Cancel">

        </form>
<?php
     $a = 123;
     $b = 234;
     $c = $_POST["username"];
     $d = $_POST["password"];
     $e = "Hello World!!";
     $f = "Error 404 Page Not Found";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if ($a == $c && $b == $d )
    {
    print "$e";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$f";
    }
}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put your php code in some other page and provide link of that page in your `<form action ="">`

Comment: `<form action="">` will post the form to itself, so use `<form action="another-page.php">` to post to another page. Some advice, use variable names that mean something. So instead of `$c` use `$username` and `$password` instead of `$d` etc.

Comment: ok I will try that on Thank You :)

Comment: Consider using your better variable names also!

Comment: Thank you very much it Worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all this will be the `html` part in a separate part like `login.html`:-**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="post"><!-- if you will not give action then form will posted to the same page -->
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter The Username"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            <input type="reset"  value="Cancel"><!-- about this i cannot say anything -->
        </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Now in `login.php`:-**

```
<?php
     $original_user_name = 123; // take variable name that are self descriptive
     $original_user_password = 234;
     $form_username = $_POST["username"];
     $form_password = $_POST["password"];
     // $e = "Hello World!!"; no need of extra variable
     // $f = "Error 404 Page Not Found"; no need of extra variable

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){ // check with POSTED values not with button value
    if ($original_user_name == $form_username && $original_user_password == $form_password){
         echo "hello World!";
    }else{
        echo "Error 404 Page Not Found!";
    }
}else{
    echo "please fill both user name and password!";
}
?>
```

Note:- both files must be in the same working directory.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the header function and it would look like this:

```
 if ($a == $c && $b == $d )
    {
     header("location: newpage.php");
     exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$f";
    }
```

or indeed as stated above me redirect the form to the new page

Answer (score -1):

Create a new `.php` file where you can put your `PHP` code & in the `html` file, change form tag to `< form action="path of that php file" method="post">`

Comment: really. don't you think it must be a comment?

Comment: According to the question this is the answer. So why should i comment it??

Comment: you will get it very soon.

Comment: It has been answered in the comments but, by all means, add another `method` he could use - not the exact same as the comments state.

Comment: You'll understand the site soon enough, like @Anant said